# Bootstrap - DIV overflow when content is set position: fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I'm trying to make some div content be sticky, but the content refuses to be constrained to the parent div, since it's fixed.

I was wondering if there are any CSS tricks I can use, instead of having to set a `width` on `.sticky-block`. Worst case, I can just set different `widths` based on the Bootstrap breakpoint. But I'd rather the fixed div somehow make use of Bootstrap's columns.

http://output.jsbin.com/savoza

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="sticky-block">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, quod deleniti voluptatibus quaerat eaque aspernatur fuga, quo perspiciatis ab, neque eveniet adipisci id sunt facere animi alias nihil pariatur suscipit!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        [...lots of content...]
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sticky-block {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This could be done fairly simply in javascript, you interested in a solution in JS or are you looking for a CSS solution

Comment: @Matthew Would prefer purely CSS. I'd even rather resort to setting a width, as I'd like to keep the code as lean as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `col-sm-6` to the sticky-block.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="sticky-block col-sm-6">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam, quod deleniti voluptatibus quaerat eaque aspernatur fuga, quo perspiciatis ab, neque eveniet adipisci id sunt facere animi alias nihil pariatur suscipit!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        [...lots of content...]
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add a max-width so that it doesn't overflow when the page is bigger than the container.

```
.sticky-block.col-sm-6 {
    max-width: 585px;
}
```

Then just add some padding to the top of your `[lots of content]` div on the 768px CSS breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed container will inherit the width from the parent value.

```
.sticky-block {
    width: inherit; 
    max-width: 585px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I added a max-width like jonathan and it gives the same result.

Comment: If you are righting this responsively then you will need to handle each break point differently.